# OSX application testing with OCMock

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, cocoa, ocmock

I am getting started with OSX TDD and OCMock, following http://pathfindersoftware.com/2009/01/testing-delegate-ocmock/.

Right now, I'm at the phase where my application displays a login upon startup and wish to test that a user with invalid/no credentials cannot login.

In detail, the AppDelegate will set itself as the login view controller's delegate, attempt to login (without setting credentials), then the delegate method `didNotAuthorizeUser` is called. However I'm getting an error in the test. Further details below.

## Object setup

- AppDelegate - real object, instantiates the login vc and conforms to its protocol (`SomeDelegateProtocol`)
- LoginVC - mocked
- Application - mocked

## Test.m

```
id mocklvc = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[LoginViewController class]];

[appDelegate setLoginViewController:mocklvc];

id qtApp = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[NSApplication class]];

id loginDelegate = [OCMockObject mockForProtocol:@protocol(SomeDelegate)];

[[mocklvc expect] setLoginDelegate:loginDelegate]; 
[[mocklvc expect] authenticateWithService];
[[loginDelegate expect] didNotAuthorizeUser];


//This row returns NSInternalConsistencyException
//OCMockObject[LoginViewController]
//unexpected method invoked setLoginDelegate:<AppDelegate>
[appDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:qtApp]; 

[mocklvc verify];
```

## AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{        
    [self.loginViewController setLoginDelegate:self];
}
```

## LoginViewController.h/.m

@property (weak) id < SomeDelegate > loginDelegate;

## Error message

When calling the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: I get the following error in the test,

`NSInternalConsistencyException OCMockObject[LoginViewController] unexpected method invoked setLoginDelegate:<AppDelegate>`

Do you think this is a good setup in the first place? Any ideas on how to rewrite the test or actually get around the error?

Comment: The error your seeing suggests that either `setLoginDelegate:` is not getting called at all, or it is not getting called with `loginDelegate` as its argument. This makes some sense because I don't how your app delegate would know about the login delegate mock you created. I'd break your test down into two parts -- one testing that login gets called on launch, and the other testing the login controller directly. You might want to read through someone else's tests to get a feel for how they should be constructed.

Comment: I exchanged the argument to appDelegate - as that is the actual argument being called in the AppDelegate.m. Sometimes these little comments do guide one on the right path :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange `loginDelegate` for `appDelegate` resolves the issue.